# Latent typing using interface and Enum

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have an `IDevice` interface and two enum realizations of this interface: `AndroidDevice` and `IosDevice`.
The issue is: I want to use latent typing and call `values()` method on an interface reference:

```
private IDevice getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml, IDevice devices) {
    for(IDevice device : devices.values()){
    //...
```

So I have to add `public IDevice[] values();` to my interface:

```
public interface IDevice {
     //...
     public IDevice[] values();
}
```

But it doesn't work. Eclipse asks me to `remove static modifiers from AndroidDevice(...)`

---

Please:

1. Explain to me why it doesn't work?
2. What is the best solution to this problem, should I use reflection instead?

Comment: showt the code of  `AndroidDevice `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a type intersection:

```
private <T extends Enum<T> & IDevice> T getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml, Class<T> deviceClass) {
    for (T device : deviceClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (<some-condition>)
            return device;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The bound to `Enum<T>` ensures that `deviceClass.getEnumConstants()` will return values, and the bound to `& IDevice` ensures you'll get an `IDevice` back.

Call it like:

```
enum IosDevice implements IDevice {
    iPhone, iPad, MacBook;
}

IDevice d = getDeviceByReadableName("<foo/>", IosDevice.class);
```

Answer (score 7):

Reason why it doesn't work is because a static `values()` method is implicitly defined for every enum.

```
public enum IOS {

    //Compiler raises an error that values() method is already defined.
    public IOS[] values(){

    }
}
```

So, when you have a static method already defined, you can't add a new instance level method with same signature.

The easiest way to fix it is to use a different method name.

```
public interface IDevice {

    IDevice[] allvalues();
}

public enum IOS implements IDevice{

    IPHONE, IPAD;

    @Override
    public IDevice[] allvalues() {
        //return array of iOS devices;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. The code doesn't work because your enumerations that are implementing the IDevice interface have two conflicting definitions of the `values()` method, so your code won't compile. Since you asked for credible and official references, I'll drill down. First, note that enums implicitly create a *static* `values()` method (see [JVM spec sec. 8.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)). However, your IDevice interface method has an *instance* method called `values()`, also. Note that when a class implementing an interface extends a base class, that newly defined method in the sub-class will override existing implementations defined from the base class. Thus, the implementation of IDevice's instance values() method is overriding the existing static definition of the values() method (see [JVM spec sec. 8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)). As per that section, it is a compile time error for an instance method to override a static method.
2. I don't think that reflection will help because this is a compile-time issue. Instead, I would recommend that `IDevice` instead define a method that is similar to `values()`, say `getValues()`, where the implementation of `getValues()` just calls `values()`. See the following code snippet. The full code can be viewed in the [demo on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/waRsIi):

   ```
   enum IosDevice implements IDevice {
       IOS1, IOS2;

       public IDevice[] getValues() {
           return IosDevice.values();
       }
   }

   enum AndroidDevice implements IDevice {
       AND1, AND2;

       public IDevice[] getValues() {
           return AndroidDevice.values();
       }
   }

   interface IDevice {
       //...
       public IDevice[] getValues();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for a good and detailed answer! I gave the boundary to  @Bohemian, since he provided more sophisticated solution.

Answer (score 4):

You are approaching this from the wrong end. Let the enum classes handle the checks instead:

### Java 7

```
public interface IDevice {
    IDevice getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml);
}
```

```
public enum AndroidDevice implements IDevice {
    HTC, SAMSUNG;

    @Override
    public IDevice getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml) {
        for (IDevice device : values())
            if (...something...)
                return device;

        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public enum IosDevice implements IDevice {
    IPHONE, IPAD;

    @Override
    public IDevice getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml) {
        for (IDevice device : values())
            if (...something...)
                return device;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
    private IDevice getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml, IDevice devices) {
        return devices.getDeviceByReadableName(versionInXml);
    }
```

### Java 8

If you are on Java 8 (lucky you!), you can do this with some extra magic:

```
public interface IDevice {
    Optional<IDevice> getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml);

    default Optional<IDevice> getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml, Stream<IDevice> devices) {
        return devices.filter((IDevice device) -> {
            return true; // put useful check here
        }).findFirst();
    }
}
```

```
public enum AndroidDevice implements IDevice {
    HTC, SAMSUNG;

    @Override
    public Optional<IDevice> getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml) {
        return getDeviceByReadableName(versionInXml, Arrays.stream(values()));
    }
}
```

```
public enum IosDevice implements IDevice {
    IPHONE, IPAD;

    @Override
    public Optional<IDevice> getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml) {
        return getDeviceByReadableName(versionInXml, Arrays.stream(values()));
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
    private Optional<IDevice> getDeviceByReadableName(String versionInXml, IDevice devices) {
        return devices.getDeviceByReadableName(versionInXml);
    }
```

Comment: In Java 8: if you want to, you could even send the `Predicate` as an argument :)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Explain me why it doesn't work?

By having `values()` declared in your `IDevice` interface and then an `Enum` implementing it you won't encounter an issue until compilation.

This is because the compiler will put in a `static` `values()` method returning an array of all the values in the enumeration, hence it will complain saying remove the `static` modifier.

You cannot override the instance method `values()` defined in `IDevice` with a `static` method of the same signature which is what the compiler is essentially trying to do.

> 2. What is the best solution of this problem, should I use reflection instead?

You should perhaps just use your `IDevice` interface as a tag with no methods?

See the following for more info:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

Comment: As for a solution, other than what I said, I would agree somewhat with Tomas

Answer (score 1):

This question can not be answered without seeing at least the method declarations in `AndroidDevice`. I assume the `AndroidDevice#values()` method is marked as `static`, which is not allowed following the inheritance rules in Java (possibly in no OO language). The reason for this is that static means that the method "lives" on the class and you don't need an instance to access the method. In an interface you declare so called instance methods, so you need an instance to access the method. You need to use instance methods when you need to operate on states, which you want to do in your case by accessing the instance values. You can not statically (via class) access instance methods or states, because the context would not be known.

So without knowing the AndroidDevice code I suggest to rethink about the way you want to access the `values()` method. IMHO the static access is not correct. If you think static access is correct for you, you might want to have a look at static interface methods that were introduced with Java 8.

But again, whenever you have a state and want to access that state, static access is not the correct object oriented way to do it.